# My urls no longer point to my pages Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

On a wagtail site I have lost links to my blog pages (possibly as a result of moving to a newer version)

My blog listing page is still accessible with the url "http://localhost:8080/blog/"

I have  the following models

```
class BlogListingPage(Page):
    template = "home/blog_listing_page.html"
    subpage_types = ['home.BlogDetailPage']

    blog_listing_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text="Heading for the blog listing page",
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("blog_listing_title"),
    ]


class BlogDetailPage(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""
    template = "home/blog_detail_page.html"

    parent_page_types = ['home.BlogListingPage']

    blog_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        help_text="Blog title (100 chars max)",
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("blog_title"),
    ]
```

I can list the blog pages in my blog listing page:

```
        {{ blog_listing.get_children.specific}}
        {% for blog in blog_listing.get_children.live %}
            <h5><a href="{% pageurl blog %}">{{ blog.specific.blog_title}}</a></h5>
            <h5><a href="{{ blog.slug }}">{{ blog.slug }}</a></h5>
        {% endfor %}
```

The *slug* displays correctly (e.g. /blog/xxx/) but the *pageurl blog* is *None* and if I click on it I get a 404 error (Request URL:   http://localhost:8080/blog/xxx/)

Finally, even if I put *http://localhost:8080/blog/xxx/* in the browser I get a 404 error

The line

```
{{ blog_listing.get_children.specific}}
```

displays the page queryset with the list of wagtail.core.models.Pages as I would expect

If I enter the following code into views

**views.py**

```
pqs = BlogListingPage.objects.all()
children = pqs.live()[0].get_children()
for child in children:
    print('s', child.slug, '|', child.url_path)
```

I get the output

> s xxx | /blog/xxx/

Which is what I expect.

Why are the pages/links no longer in sync?

I cannot post an MRE because, ironically, when I try to construct one, it works as expected. I cannot see what the difference is with my live site, but if someone could point to where I might look it would help.

Comment: What version were you on and what version did you update to?

Comment: I was on 2.11.3 and now 2.16.2

Comment: This is odd, the only thing I can see is a change in 2.13 `Allow `{% pageurl %}` fallback to be a direct URL or an object with a `get_absolute_url` method`.
Are you able to upgrade one release at a time and see where it breaks?
When you open the live link (from the admin) is the page working, what is that URL?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - got dragged to another project. I've downgraded wagtail, but it still does not work. What is the 'live link'? Preview? The preview works, but it is not pointing to the url